# source code for kafka_2.9.2,version 0.8.2.1

Tags: maven, jar, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

How do i compile the source code for the following dependency.
Also where can i get the source code for the same dependency? Please provide me a link. I want to compile the source code after adding few logs.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also i have a question like, when i am adding this dependency in my code,i am getting many other dependency jars as well such as:

```
scala-library-2.9.2.jar
metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.1.jar
snappy-java.jar
zookeeper.jar
```

I understand there requirement but i dont get these jars in lib folder of kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.1, when i unzip it!!
Any idea  where am i doing wrong!!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the source code should be to fork the git repository: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/0.8.2

Have a look at the README file -- it explains how to compile Kafka.